# SMBclient put file does not exist

Tags: linux, samba, smb, smbclient

I am trying to write a cron script which will copy a file from an SMB share to my local linux folder.

I am connecting to the share like this...

```
/usr/bin/smbclient \\\\myserver\\myshare
```

It connects correctly and if I issue dir I can see the file I want myfile.txt

I am then trying to copy it like this...

```
put myfile.txt /home/myuser
```

This gives me an error like this...

```
myfile.txt does not exist
```

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`put` copies files **to the server**. If you want to *get* files from the share, use `get`.

Comment: Obviously, can't believe I missed that!